# Native extension .node in Windows to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, native-code

I built a .node extension in Windows using the following code (addon.node):

```
 #include "v8.h"
 #include  "node.h"
 extern "C" void NODE_EXTERN init (Handle<Object> target)
 {
   HandleScope scope;
   target->Set(String::New("hello"), String::New("world"));
 }
 NODE_MODULE(hello, init)
```

I compiled in VS10 and my simple code in main.js is:

```
 var addon = require("./addon.node");
 console.log(addon.hello());
```

It should be print the word "world", but I have the following error:

```
 #
 # Fatal error in d:\nodejs\deps\v8\src\objects-inl.h, line 3199
 # CHECK(heap->isolate() == Isolate::Current()) failed
 #
```

Anyone knows the solution?
Thanks in advance!

SOLVED: My problem was that I included the library to SSL support. I remove it and done!

Comment: Please Put The Solution In An Answer